# Openpyxl - Merge Empty Column Cells Delimited by String

Tags: python, loops, merge, cell, openpyxl

I've been doing some big data work, and I've been writing a script to automate the formatting of a 15,000+ row .csv into a formatted excel file.  I've been using Openpyxl for most of the formatting work.

I need to merge the server name cells in the ***Hostname*** column with the empty cells below it, but can't seem to get it working.  In the table below, I need to merge ***Dev Server*** with all of the empty cells below it (to stop at ***RAS Server***).  Then merge ***RAS Server*** with the empty cells below that, and ***Prod Server*** with the empty cells below that.

The issue I'm having is I can't seem to specify the right `for` loop that identifies a cell with a string, iterates through each of the cells below it (merging with the empty cells), and then stopping and starting a new merged cell at the next cell containing a string.

Specified parameters/cell numbers cannot work here - the real table is 15,000+ lines long, and the amount of 'installed software' on each server ranges from 25-200+ per server.  To make things better, the real server names also have no consistent naming pattern or scheme.

**Is this possible?  Any help or direction would be much appreciated.**

| Hostname | Installed Software |
| --- | --- |
| Dev Server | Microsoft Word |
|  | Microsoft Excel |
|  | Microsoft Teams |
|  | Visual Studio Code |
|  | Discord |
| RAS Server | Microsoft Word |
|  | Spotify |
|  | Log4j |
| Prod Server | Adobe Photoshop |
|  | Unreal Engine |
|  | Adobe PDF Reader |
|  | Steam |
|  | Adobe Illustrator |
|  | Hyper-V |

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Test.xlsx")  # Load Workbook
ws = wb["Sheet1"]                         # Load Worksheet

    total_rows = []  # Used to enumerate the total number of rows
                     # in the Worksheet

    for i in range (1,20000):
        if ws["B" + str(i)].value != None:
            total_rows.append(i)  # If the cell has a string, the
                                  # cell row number is appended to 
                                  # total_rows.  Indexing the last 
                                  # number in total_rows will give
                                  # you the total number of rows
    
    cells_with_strings = []
    for i in range (1,(total_rows[-1])):
        if ws["A" + str(i)].value != None:
            cells_with_strings.append(int(i))
            # Iterates through each cell in column A, and appends
            # the row numbers of cells containing text to cells_with_strings
    
    merge_cell_range = len(cells_with_strings) - 1
    for i in range (0, (merge_cell_range)):
        ws.merge_cells("A" + str(cells_with_strings[i]) + ":" + "A" + str((cells_with_strings[(i+1)])-1))
        # Using the values in cell_with_strings, it merges the cells in the rows
        # represented by the values in cells_with_strings.  This works for all 
        # merges except for the last merge.
    
    final_merge = []
    for i in range ((cells_with_strings[-1]), ((cells_with_strings[-1]) + 9999)):
        if ws["B" + str(i)].value != None:
            final_merge.append(int(i))
    ws.merge_cells("A" + str(final_merge[0]) + ":" + "A" + str(final_merge[-1]))
    # The last row merge requires different code to the iteration merge.

wb.save("Test.xlsx")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).